# What is the maximum size of the bitmap returned by the Camera Intent data?

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, camera

In my android sample camera application, I launch the device's Camera application as follows:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Retrieve the Bitmap via Intent data as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  
data)
{
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
   {
      Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
      Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
   }
}
```

I tested this sample app with 2 android mobile of different dimensions
Results as follows:
Phone 1:
   Dimensions of the original image captured by camera is 2988x5312. But size of bitmap is 124x221
Phone2:
   Dimensions of the original image captured by camera is 1456x2592. But size of bitmap is 91x162

My Questions:
A. I just want to know what is the maximum size of the bitmap thumbnail returned by the Intent?
B. How they calculate the size ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know what is the maximum size of the bitmap thumbnail returned by the Intent?

It will vary by device and camera app. You are guaranteed that it will be under 1MB, as there is a limit as to how much data can be sent back via `onActivityResult()`.

> How they calculate the size ?

It will vary by device and camera app.

Comment: Thanks CommonWare. I want to know based on what parameter or what calculation the size of bitmap is decided ? Is there any calculation for that?

Comment: @PM16: **It will vary by device and camera app**. If you decide to write your own camera app, you can decide yourself how you want to handle it. The only technical requirement, besides the extra being named `data`, is that the `Bitmap` needs to be small enough to avoid a `FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION` exception, which occurs when a Binder-based IPC transaction exceeds 1MB. In my CWAC-Cam2 library, I keep the `Bitmap` under 750KB.

Answer (score 0):

To get the full-sized image you need to write file to EXTERNAL_STORAGE by creating a fileProvider to android.

In Manifest and add this code

```
   <provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
   </provider>
```

Create file_path

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <external-path name="my_images" 
   path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
   </paths>
```

you can follow  this link 
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html